# Mysql trigger ON INSERT + INNER JOIN syntax error

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers, syntax-error

I have an assignment from uni where i need to simulate something like Spotify (without player).
Some context: The thing is i want to make a trigger so that when a new playlist is created (column on table `playlist`), the creator user (`userID`) is set as it's first follower. The table `followingPlaylist` is an intermidiate table that keeps record of which user follows which playlist. On top of that, accounts have 2 types, `artists` and `users` (so there is the table `accounts` that keeps the account info, `users` and `artists` that keep the `accountID` and `userID` or `artistID` respectively).

The problem i have is that mysql throws sintax error with this query, if anyone could help i'd be much obliged. This is the query:

```
CREATE TRIGGER primer_seguidor ON playlists
FOR INSERT AS
    INSERT INTO followingPlaylist
    (accountID, playlistID)
    SELECT
    playlists.playlistID, users.accountID FROM playlists
    INNER JOIN usuers ON playlists.userID = users.userID;
```

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help clarify what you want to do.

Comment: MySQL have no `ON INSERT` triggers support. Please read [User Manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-trigger.html) and study the list of trigger events.

Comment: *mysql throws sintax error with this query* If you report about syntax error then you MUST publish direct, unchanged and non-shortened, error message text.

Comment: @Akina well is a good thing that this part is the assignment is not necessary because otherways i would be screwed, thanks for the input.

Comment: If you want to insert a row(s) into another, linked, table, then you must use AFTER INSERT trigger (i.e. only when insertion is already performed successfully, without error). Pay attention that in MySQL the triggers are row-based, i.e. they processes each separate inserted row, not all inserted rows in a complex (FOR EACH ROW keywords in the syntax). So for the reference of the values inserted into the table which the trigger is defined on you must use not the table alias but NEW single-row pseudotable alias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CREATE TRIGGER primer_seguidor 
AFTER INSERT
ON playlists
FOR EACH ROW
    INSERT INTO followingPlaylist (accountID, playlistID)
    SELECT NEW.playlistID, users.accountID 
    FROM users 
    WHERE NEW.userID = users.userID;
```

PS. Syntax correction only, no logic checking.

PPS. [Modelling fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/7k5a74GPKQwwvpma8Un8PG/0)

Comment: Thank you, this did exactly what i wanted. Much obliged!